# Typescript function argument validation

Tags: typescript, types, jwt

This is my second day with **typescript** and I am confused about this kind of scenario:

Assuming we have a `.env` file with an `ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET` variable

```
ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = 9i0d98f7a0sd87fy03eihdq2iudh...
```

We may want to pass that variable to a function in our ts code, for example:

```js
const accessToken = jwt.sign(user, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)
```

At this point our ide should tell us that the process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET may not be a **string**

```
Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Secret'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Secret'.ts(2345)
```

So, I fixed this checking if the process variable is actually a **string**

```js
if(typeof process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET !== 'string') throw new Error()
const accessToken = jwt.sign(user, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)
```

But I do not feel that comfortable with this solution, is this the correct way ts expects me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. That is a correct way of handling this.

Another one would be to just check for `undefined` as that is also enough for TS to narrow the type. Something like this

```
if (process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET) {
  const accessToken = jwt.sign(user, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)
}
```

Another way would be to bail early:

```
if (process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET === undefined) {
  return; //or throw an error
}
```